# what is multisample per pixel in directx11 DXGI_SAMPLE_DECS

Tags: c++, directx, dxgi

I was reading documentation about `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC` and i came across with [`DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgicommon/ns-dxgicommon-dxgi_sample_desc)

> `Count`
> Type: UINT
> The number of multisamples per pixel.

now what exactly is `multisamples per pixel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DXGI_SAMPLE_DESC` as you surmised is for specifying Multi-Sample Anti-Aliasing ([MSAA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisample_anti-aliasing)).

That said, you should be aware that the SwapChain support for MSAA is not something you should use anymore. As such, just always set `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC.SampleDesc.Count = 1;` and `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;`.

Instead, to use MSAA you should explicitly create your own MSAA render target and explicitly resolve the result yourself as part of your presentation of the results to the single-sample SwapChain. For details on why and how, see [this blog post series](https://walbourn.github.io/care-and-feeding-of-modern-swapchains/).

Note that you *can* use MSAA SwapChains for DirectX 11 with the older `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD` and `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_SEQUENTIAL` flip-effects, and the DirectX 11 runtime will do the resolve automatically. Per the blog post, this is NOT supported for DirectX 12 or the use of modern `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD` or `DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL` swap effects. This is really a 'toy' setup as any production rendering will do additional processing after the resolve from multi-sample to single-sample before putting it into the swapchain for display.

> As you are likely new to DirectX 11, you may want to look at [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started). I have a tutorial that covers MSAA.

Answer (score 0):

ok it is `anti-aliasing` (my bad i didn't know that)

> Anti-aliasing is a technique used by users to get rid of jaggies that form on the screen. Since pixels are rectangular, they form small jagged edges when used to display round edges. Anti-aliasing tries to smooth out the shape and produce perfect round edges.